# Include file and catch errors if it has any

Tags: php

I am using PHP to write an application. The application allows for running scripts placed in a a folder. The concern I have though is that when it does this if a script has an error it will crash the application and then the remaining scripts will not be ran.

I have a similar issue in another place of my application. Where I include files full of functions that are loaded into the application. The concern is that if one of these secondary functions causes an error I don't want it to stop my application.

The questions I have is if there is a way to get a include and if there is an error with the code in the include do something? My thought was try catch, but I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: Well, one would assume that you need to include the scripts to make your application run. If the scripts has an issue it has to be addressed (read fixed!), not ignored.

Comment: you don't need to include a file to run it as a script.
You don't need to ignore an error or let it go crash "untreated".
what have you tried so far (your code) and what is puzzling you (in that code)

Comment: The scripts I am including only contain ancillary functions and not core functions for the application this why I want to be able to treat them in this way. Think wordpress plugin. The issue though is what I would really like is a way to detect when they have fatal errors so I can disable them. I really wanted something like

try {
   include($file)
} catch {
  //disable future includes of this $file as it had an error in it or soemthing in it threw an error 
}

Answer (score 0):

It depends on kind of the errors you are getting, but maybe `@include` could be a remedy?

Answer (score 0):

In php the include (or require) functionality actually copies the code from that file to the current file and the executes the code as one. If the included script has an error you have to address it in the file by using the error supression operator [@](http://no.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). PHP has several layers of errors so the type of error is also important. Some of the error reporting can be deactivated by some directives like *[error_reporting](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)*. Otherwise error management in a good library is handled by exceptions (see *[set_exception_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)*). For *try-catch* blocks look [here](http://no.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

In general showing the errors is what you want in developing and testing environments, but not on production, because there it can lead to security problems.